# Laravel Query Where Relationship within Relationship Condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eager-loading

Been trying to resolve this query for a long time now, it's working but there is a bit of misquery.

This is one of my queries from my search function with livewire.

```
return empty($search)
    ? static::query()  
    : static::query()->where('id','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('status.user',function($q) use ($search){
            $q->where('active',1)
                ->where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$search.'%');
        });
```

For example, I type the name of 'jason' the query will return the correct result, but if I type Jason's username it will return every record that Jason's been update (but not active) I just want the action to return with a particular name or username.

I already try to separate the active, name, and username on different functions but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AND** has precedence over **OR** so this condition

```
$q->where('active',1)
  ->where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$search.'%');
```

is evaluating like - `where ( active = 1 and name like '%$search%' ) or username like '%$search%'`

But if I am not wrong then your want something like `where active = 1 and ( name like '%$search%' or username like '%$search%')`

To achieve this you can try segregating above condition like -

```
 $q->where('active',1)
   ->where(function($q2) use ($search){
         $q2->where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
         $q2->orWhere('username','like','%'.$search.'%');
 });
```

Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: This solve my problem and i use this $q2->where('username','like','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('name','like','%'.$search.'%'); instead just personal preference. Thank you!